# Issue JNDI resource initialization - DB connection @"DB2 on Cloud - BLUEMIX

Tags: db2, jndi, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

We are unable to make DB2 database connection from Java application deployed on "Liberty on Java" using JNDI resource at Bluemix.

It is not able to initialize the resource.

My server.xml file is

```
 "<dataSource id="eVotingDataSource" jdbcDriverRef="db2-driver" jndiName="jdbc/DatabaseName" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <properties.db2.jcc id="eVotingDataSource-props" databaseName="*******" user="db2inst1" password="******" portNumber="50001" serverName="********" sslConnection="true"/>
</dataSource>
<jdbcDriver id="db2-driver" libraryRef="db2-library"/>
<library id="db2-library">
    <fileset id="db2-fileset" dir="${server.config.dir}/lib" includes="db2jcc4.jar db2jcc_license_cu.jar"/>
</library>
```

Web.xml file

```
<resource-ref>
<description>DB Connection</description>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/DatabaseName</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
```

applicationContext.xml file

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="eVotingDataSource"
```

jndi-name="jdbc/DatabaseName"
expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

Below is output of messages.log

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.nl.abnamro.evoting.dao.IssuerDAOImpl.eVotingSessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eVotingSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'eVotingDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eVotingDataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: CWWKN0008E: An object could not be obtained for name jdbc/DatabaseName.
>
> Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eVotingDataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: CWWKN0008E: An object could not be obtained for name jdbc/DatabaseName.
>
> Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eVotingMailSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Intermediate context does not exist: mail/Session

When we load the application we receive the following error:

> Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [springSecurityFilterChain]: could not be initialized

Could you please assist?

Comment: Is the feature jndi-1.0 configured for the Liberty server?

Comment: Hi...Yes...it is added in server.xml file

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving is related with this configuration from your server.xml

```
jndiName="**jdbc/DatabaseName**"

CWWKN0008E: An object could not be obtained for name **jdbc/DatabaseName**.
```

If you are using a DB service bound using Bluemix, the runtime is automatically configured when your application is staging, so you usually don't need to provide your own configuration in your server.xml overwriting the Bluemix configuration.
Instead, if you need to overwrite the server.xml for your own configurations, you could access the DB service references on your Bluemix page, on the Bluemix console under the 'Environment Variables' section 
[image]

You could retrieve the DBService name to use inside your server.xml as JNDI/[DBNAME]

You could also retrieve the right Datasource to use simply deploying your app on Bluemix without overwriting the server.xml and check on the Bluemix UI (under Files section) the value of the Datasource on the produced server.xml

Just a little question: Could you confirm that you are pushing your application along with your server.xml, within a packaged version of your liberty run-time ?

Comment: Hi, Here I am using "DB2 on cloud" This service is not bound to the application in Bluemix. So, I dont have anything in Environmental variables section in BLuemix.  Also, I am pushing the application along with server.xml file.  Can you please help if something wrong with the definition

Comment: Hi, to connect to db2 on cloud you should use a jdbc connection string like described here https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/DB2OnCloud/index.html

Comment: Otherwise if you wish to use jndi reference, you have to define a data source in your server.xml like this one <dataSource id="db2" jndiName="jdbc/mydb" type="javax.sql.DataSource"> <jdbcDriver libraryRef="DB2JCC4Lib"/> <properties.db2.jcc databaseName="[db-name]" password="[your-password]" portNumber="[db-port-number]" serverName="[db-server]" user="[your-username]"/> </dataSource>.   You can find an example here /answers/questions/164214/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-database-outside-bluemi.html

Comment: Ok check that you are using a right configuration in your bean conf, you should have something like that:

<bean id="eVotingDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/DatabaseName"/>
</bean>

If your bean configuration is wrong, your bean is referencing a wrong DB connection